# Get the locator of the element upon which mouse is hovered/clicked

Tags: html, events, dom, webdriver

I want to know a way of extracting id/locator of the element in the dom on which mouse is hovered/clicked. I want to capture this in my code.

Ex:
Consider a web page which has a button with id=saveButton.
I will be running the deamon code at the back end.
When a user clicks the button, I want my code to capture the mouse event which is click and locator which is @saveButton.

Please let me know how to do this. Code in jave would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With "jave", you mean JavaScript?

Comment: Do you want a recorder for Selenium ? There is one for Selenium 1, which is integrated in the Selenium IDE, an Add On for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 different option I know of:

**[Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)**

As Boris said in the comments...Selenium IDE is a Firefox extension that will record what you do and export it into code you can execute.

However...there are some serious disadvantages to this:

Your code becomes fragile.  The selectors it generates may or may not be the best ones for the job.

It uses Selenium 1.  Selenium 2 is much better.

**[Selenium Builder:](http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/)**

However, there is an open source project called Selenium Builder.  It can export your tests to Selenium 2.  However, its not as widely used, and it has the same first problem...it may or may not generate the best selector.

Finally...if you are just looking to generate selectors, you could either **right-click on an element (in Chrome) and generate XPath**, or you could generate CSS selectors using a bookmarklet called **[Selector Gadget:](http://selectorgadget.com/)**

Of everything I've tried, I've found Selector Gadget to be the best at making a selector that is unique but not fragile.

*However, will all of these tools...I would recommend learning how CSS/XPath selectors work before using them, so you actually understand what your tests are doing.*